# Special sorting pivot table Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am having difficulties trying to sort my pandas pivot table.

So, I am parsing a dataset in HTML on the web and wrangles it to fit it in a DataFrame.

What I have now looks like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Customer', 'Paper', 'Exch', 'Quantity', 'Max sell', 'Value', 'Borrowed'])
df = df.drop(df.columns[[2,4,6]], axis=1)
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df[['Value', 'Quantity']] = df[['Value', 'Quantity']].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df = df.clip(lower=0)
df = df[df.Paper != '*Cash']
df = df.dropna()


df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Value', 'Quantity'], index=['Paper', 'Customer'], aggfunc=sum)


print df.to_string()
```

And it outputs this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuQF4.png)

It is sorting alphabetically on 'Stock and then 'Customer'. I want it to sort on 'Value' but in the same pivot format like it outputs now.

This is what I want:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iVUH.png)

Bonus: How can I add another column with percent of total and display all of this in a simple bar chart?

I would be so happy if someone can help with this. Thank you!

EDIT: Forgot to paste the pd.pivot_table code. Now in place.

Comment: Did you try [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html): `df.sort_values('Value', ascending = False)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried sort_values, sort_index, but then it only sorts on values and discards the pivot format.

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. You can add a list in sort_values: `['Value', 'Customer']` and pivot format is retained. Please show your attempt and current and desired result.